# Read and print a user selected file's contents

Tags: python, user-input

I wrote a script by using python3.3 that opens and reads a file by the user's input.

```
txt_file = input("Text File: ")

f = open(txt_file,"r")
txt_include = f.read()

print(txt_include)
```

It tells me that "txt_include is not defined"

I couldn't find a way to put txt variable in open function. I used many functions to have variable with quotation but nothing worked.

What is the right syntax that I should use?

Comment: Please provide any errors you are receiving. And what version of Python are you using? 2.7 or 3+ ?

Comment: I've edited my post in your guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, a better method would be:

```
import os

def print_file_contents(file_path):
    assert os.path.exists(file_path), "File does not exist: {}".format(file_path)
    with open(file_path) as f:
        print (f.read())

user_input = raw_input("Enter a file path: ") # just input(...) in Python 3+
print_file_contents(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

f = open(txt,"r") should be `f = open(txt_file,"r")`

and use `raw_input` instead of `input` as with input your input data will be interpreted as python variable, not a string.

Comment: sorry. i wrote that here wrong.  in my script it's like f = open(txt_file,"r")

Comment: The print statement implies `python 3`, where `input()` would be correct.

Comment: Print statement is also valid for python 2.7 where input behaves as mentioned in my answer. http://ideone.com/DVUSN4

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is called `txt_file`, not `txt`. Change the naming to be consistent and it should work.

Comment: sorry. i wrote that here wrong. in my script it's like f = open(txt_file,"r")

Answer (score 0):

Your are using the wrong variable name - it is `txt_file`, not `txt`.

```
txt_file = input("Text File: ")

f = open(txt_file, "r")
```

Edit:  OK, so now you changed the code in the question.  So what error message are you getting?

Comment: sorry. i wrote that here wrong. in my script it's like f = open(txt_file,"r")

Comment: It tells me that f is not defined.

Comment: @cankemik:  please, when you ask a question in future, give the whole error message exactly as it appears.  And remember that error messages are your friends.